# Central moment for a uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-functions

The probability density function of T is given by

$$f(t) = 1/2h \text{, for each }  t\in(-h,h) $$
where $h > 0$. Derive an expression for the central moment

I used integration and got $\frac{(b-u)^r+1 - (a-u)^r+1}{2h(r+1)}$
is this correct?

Comment: Which central moment?

Comment: a general formula for the central moment i.e ur

Comment: $E(T-\mu)^r=E(T^r)=\int_{-h}^h \frac{x^r}{2h}\,dx=\cdots$